# matlab - turn arrays into index values

Tags: bsxfun

Given a = [1, 7] and b = [4, 10], I want to create a new vector [1:4,7:10]. I can do this with a loop, but I was looking for vectorized solution. I tried using the bsxfun by defining the following function fun = @(c,d) c:d but then using bsxfun(fun, a, b). It generates 1:4 but not 7:10. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Now that I see your answer, I see that I picked a poor example of what I was trying to accomplish. The values in the vectors a and b are not related, i.e., a(1) - b(1) = x = a(2) - b(2), and I could have more than two entries. For example: a = [1,7,15] b=[3, 12, 21] and the desired output is [1:3,7:12,15:21]

Comment: Check out the updated code? Also consider editing your newly added input case into the question, so that the posted solution maintains the sync.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you -

```
lens = (b - a)+1; %// extents of each group
maxlens = max(lens) %// maximum extent

mask = bsxfun(@le,[1:maxlens]',lens) %// mask of valid numbers
vals = bsxfun(@plus,a,[0:maxlens-1]') %// all values
out = vals(mask).' %// only valid values are collected to form desired output
```

Sample run -

```
a =
     1     7    15
b =
     3    12    21
out =
     1   2   3   7   8   9  10  11  12  15  16  17  18  19  20  21
```